Setting up GCP with Azure SSO using Cloud Identity
I want to set up GCP with Azure AD user provisioning and single signon (SSO) without using Google Workspace. I have previously followed this path but have now gotten an email from Google that on lack of increase in storage quota for Google Workspace, my Cloud Identity Free will be suspended.
I am not in need of services offered by Google Workspace and only need to use GCP with my organization. I am unable to find proper documentation which helps you set up SSO with Azure without going through Google Workspace.
Has anyone else experienced this before and managed to figure out the solution?
Do you recommend a specific subscription of Cloud Identity or Workspace instead to be able to use GCP?

Here's a reference documentation from Takweb Tech that you can check to setup your GCP with Azure AD user provisioning and single sign-on.
Overview:

Create a GCP Account

2 Create an Organizational Unit and Provisioning Account in GCP

Set Up SSO in Azure AD

Configure SSO in GCP

Set Up User Provisioning in Azure AD


